# Parse long date format in Perl

Tags: perl, date, datetime

Is there a module for perl that will parse this format of date into a `DateTime` object?

> Thursday, September 13, 2007

I have tried [`DateTime::Format::Natural`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Format::Natural) but it doesn't seem to work.

I would prefer a function that doesn't mind if there isn't a day of the week, for instance.  I can't be sure if the data will be consistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved using [DateTime::Format::Flexible](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime::Format::Flexible).

```
use DateTime::Format::Flexible qw( );

my $dt = DateTime::Format::Flexible->parse_datetime(
   'Thursday, September 13, 2007',
   lang => [ 'en' ],                    # Optional
);
```

---

If you had known the specific format (as in your original question), I would have recommended [DateTime::Format::Strptime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime::Format::Strptime).

```
use DateTime::Format::Strptime qw( );

my $format = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
   pattern  => '%A, %B %e, %Y',
   locale   => 'en',
   on_error => 'croak',
);

my $dt = $format->parse_datetime('Thursday, September 13, 2007');
```